# Bootstrap - Move down one div from a set of divs on resizing

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

How I can move down div-B on extra-small screen size?
I have idea with xs-hidden and content duplication, but it's not what I need.

Now, my current code is like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    A
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    B
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    C
</div>
```

In lg/md/sm I have this:

```
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
| a | b | c |
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
```

But in xs I would like to get this:

```
+-----+-----+
|     |     |
| a   |  c  |
|     |     |
+-----+-----+
|           |
|     b     |
|           |
+-----------+
```

Comment: You would be best of changing the HTML structure itself if you would like `b` to sit below `c`. Currently, your `b` column sits **above** your `c` column in your HTML, and thus you can never display `c` above `b` using Bootstrap's default `col-` classes. You would need something like flexbox (or jQuery) if you don't want to swap the HTML structure.

Comment: @Obsidian, Oh, It's sad. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: @Michael, bootstrap-3

Comment: You can do it with flexbox, something like this https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/rzWaRL

Comment: @MichaelCoker, It's cute, but unfortunately my project is based on Bootstrap. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: you can try an awfull trick using the foat properties and négative margins; https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YxpPoL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's `col-sm` break-point is 768px.

So you can use the `$(window).width()` and two classes for the divs to be moved, like in the below `resize` handler example.

```js
$(window).on("resize",function(){

  //console.log( $(window).width() );

  if( $(window).width() < 768 ){
    $(".movedown").before( $(".moveup") );
  }else{
    $(".moveup").before( $(".movedown") );
  }

});
```

```css
div{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
  A
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 movedown">
  B
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 moveup">
  C
</div>
```

The example is easier to resize in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/RZobbY?editors=1111)
*It doesn't work in the snippet preview... Have to look at full page mode.*

Comment: i believe breakpoint is at 767px ;). clean answer via jQuery  , i did not dare to make one of a dirty css/html trick https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YxpPoL , the purpose was more playing with float behavior than being advised to use ... +1

Comment: @GCyrillus: Thanks! ;) If you uncomment the `console.log` in the CodePen, and resize slowwwwly... You will see that `console.log("sm")` trigs at 769px.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, GCyrillus, it's works for me. thank you guys.

Comment: I double checked about "sm" breakpoint... @GCyrillus was right, [reference here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)